# Що означає і звідки пішов вираз "курча дошка"?

Tags: сталий-вираз

У [бесіді Оксани Забужко](https://youtu.be/2YllQBITlIQ?t=3068) я почув вираз *курча дошка*:

> і далі створюється ця димова завіса і фальшиве уявлення ніби в Росії є якісь *протєстующіє* і от приїздить, розумієте, російська письменниця з лекцією про їх (пауза), де вона аналізує їхній костюм. **Курча дошка**, та проаналізуй історію російського фашизму за 30 років.

В мережі трохи є траплянь цього виразу:

- Курча дошка на ту владу.
- Націоналістки, курча дошка!
- Курча дошка, як мене то бісить.

Можу припустити, що його значення близьке до значення *трясця*, *дідько* чи подібних, але не певен. Також цікаве походження цього сталого виразу.

Щодо *курча*, то може бути оце:

> Серед прокльонів вирізняються також евфемізми, що мають на меті замінити непристойні слова іншими, які їх лише нагадують. Таким чином з'явилися замінники слова "курва" - "курча", ...
> <sub>["Львівська лайка" на rock.lviv.ua](https://rock.lviv.ua/article/5743/)</sub>